# How to enable and disable an input field using knockout when there is a checkbox?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a checkbox field and an input field (`endDate`). I want to enable and disable the `endDate` depends on the checkbox value (when the check box is checked the `endDate` is disabled and vice versa). I have the input and check box elements as follow:

> ```
> <input id="inUse" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: inUse"/>
> <input id="endDate" data-bind="datepicker: enDate, enable: enableEndDate"/>
> ```

enableEndDate:

> ```
> self.enableEndDate = ko.computed(function(){
>      return !inUse();
>     }
> });
> ```

when the page is loaded, depends on the `inUse` field value, the `endDate` would be enabled or disabled. When I uncheck the `inUse` the `endDate` would be enabled. 
Now I want to enable a disabled `endDate` when the user click on it and then change the value of `inUse` to unchecked at the same time. How can I bind this two way process?

Comment: You can use `disable: inUse` for your endDate. You don't really need the computed.

Comment: Right, or make your computed `return !self.inUse();`

Comment: @JohnnyHK What if I want to enable the endDate and uncheck the inUse box when the user clicks on endDate input box? I want to keep the previous enable/disable binding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are:

- If the user clicks the `inUse` checkbox, the textbox should be enabled or disabled, depending on the checkbox status
- If the textbox is disabled, and the user clicks it, the textbox should be enabled and the checkbox checked

First, if you disable the textbox, it will not throw events, so it's impossible to know when the user clicks it. Thus, you need to use `readonly`, instead of `disabled`. When a readonly textbox is clicked, it triggers the click event.

Knockout doesn't have a readonly binding. You could use the generic `attr` binding, or create a `readonly` handler, which is really easy:

```
// Add new binding handler for readonly
ko.bindingHandlers['readonly'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = !!ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(value !== element.readOnly)
            element.readOnly = value;
    }
};
```

This must be run after loading the knockout library, and before binding the view model. You can use `readonly` as any of the built in handlers.

Besides you can modify your CSS to make it clear that the textbox is disabled, for example like this:

```
/* Make visible when the control is disabled */
input[readonly] {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Then, the rest of the story is really simple. This is the view model and binding:

```
var vm = (function() {
    var inUse = ko.observable(false);
    var endDate = ko.observable(null);
    var endDateClick = function() {
        console.log('Clicked!');
        if (!inUse()) inUse(true);
    };
    return {
        inUse: inUse,
        endDate: endDate,
        endDateClick: endDateClick
    }
})();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And this is the corresponding HTML:

```
<input id="inUse" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: inUse"/>
<input id="endDate" data-bind="value: endDate, readonly: !inUse(), click: endDateClick"/>
```

You can see it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/Lmfc5mmn/1/). Or directly:

```js
// Add new binding handler for readonly
ko.bindingHandlers['readonly'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = !!ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(value !== element.readOnly)
            element.readOnly = value;
    }
};

var vm = (function() {
    var inUse = ko.observable(false);
    var endDate = ko.observable(null);
    var endDateClick = function() {
        console.log('Clicked!');
        if (!inUse()) inUse(true);
    };
    return {
        inUse: inUse,
        endDate: endDate,
        endDateClick: endDateClick
    };
})();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
/* Make visible when the control is disabled */
input[readonly] {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input id="inUse" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: inUse"/>
<input id="endDate" data-bind="value: endDate, readonly: !inUse(), click: endDateClick"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JotaBe. The only problem is my endDate getting its value from backend. So when the user clicks in the input box I need to change the value to false something like inUse('false') in the endDateClick function. But it does not work. How can I change the value to false?

Comment: Please, describe the problem more precisely. I don't know if you simply have to change the inUse "polarity" (i.e. change true to false or viceversa). If you describe it correctly, I can cahnge the code easily. Have you tried playing around with the fiddle? Did you have any problem with it? I'd really like to help you, but I don't have a clear view of what the problem is.

Comment: The fiddle working fine. But in my project I am getting the data(like inUse and endDate) using ajax call. So my observables are inside an object: self.myObject.inUse() and self.myObject.endDate(). I do not pass any value to them like what you did in your code.  I understand everything just when my inUse field has a value for example 'true' which comes from ajax call, how can I change the value to false when the click binding runs? my problrm is in the endDateClick function when it wants to change the value of the inUse to 'true'.

Comment: It's still difficult to understand your problem. But I'll try my best: if the problem is that you don't know what is the object that contains the `inUse` property, the functions used as event handlers in ko viewmodels can receive 2 parameters, the first being the object bound to the element that triggered the event. So, if you modify the handling function in my fidlle like this:  `var endDateClick = function(obj)`, you can check that `obj` is an object that contains the `inUse` and the other observable properties. If this isn`t the question, please add some code to your q or modify my fiddle